# I can't open this .jar file. Help! (Kubuntu Wily)

Tags: kubuntu, java

I have already checked the questions people ask about this problem. But that
was Ubuntu and I'm running Kubuntu.

I tried to set `jar` on the Application Preferences Order but there is no
such thing as `jar` so, I choose java instead.

Then I clicked OK and everything and double clicked on the file I want to open. The loading cursor changed into a jumping coffee bean but still, nothing
happened. It still won't open.

Now, after doing some gcj stuff (which I have no idea what it is), I tried to execute `java -jar PixelsinHell.jar` and it shows me this :

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:502)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:118)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:954)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
        ... 2 more
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Help, please?

Comment: Ubuntu and Kubuntu will have no differences here. Use those other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=18801) appears to have your exact error message.

It states that installing the x11-xserver-utils package is required. You can install this with `sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils`.